# Another Stable Category

Tags: modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra. For $M,N \in mod(A)$, define:

$$ \mathcal{P}_m(M,N) = \{ f\in Hom_A(M,N) | \exists \ P\in mod(A) \ with \ pd(P)=m \ and \ f \ factors \ through \ P  \}  $$

These defines an ideal of the category $mod(A)$.

What are the properties of the category $\mathcal{C}$, with:

$$ Hom_{\mathcal{C} }(M,N) = Hom_A(M,N) / \mathcal{P}_m(M,N)  $$ 
And objects the same as $mod(A)$? Has it been studied?

Observation: For $m=0$ the category $\mathcal{C}$ is the stable category of $mod(A)$.